# dropWhile creates two iterators that have same underlying iterator?

Tags: scala, iterator

I am observing, a behavior I don't fully understand:

```
scala> val a = Iterator(1,2,3,4,5)
a: Iterator[Int] = non-empty iterator

scala> val b = a.dropWhile(_ < 3)
b: Iterator[Int] = non-empty iterator

scala> b.next
res9: Int = 3

scala> b.next
res10: Int = 4

scala> a.next
res11: Int = 5
```

It looks like: iterator part `(1,2,3)` of iterator `a` is consumed, and `(4,5)` is left. Since `3` had to be evaluated it had to be consumed but by definition of `dropWhile` in has to be included in `b`. Iterator `b` is `3, (4,5)` where `(4,5)` is whatever is left of `a`, the exactly same iterator. Is my understanding correct?

Given the above it looks quite dangerous, that behavior of `b` is altered by applying operations on `a`. Basically we have two objects pointing to the same location. Is using `dropWhile` like this bad style?

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation for `Iterator`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Iterator.html):

> It is of particular importance to note that, unless stated otherwise, one should never use an iterator after calling a method on it. The two most important exceptions are also the sole abstract methods: `next` and `hasNext`.

Basically, once you called any method on an iterator, other than `next` and `hasNext`, you should consider it destroyed, and dispose of it.

Comment: That makes sense. I wonder why the language does not enforce it itself.

Comment: The language has no way to say that a value can only be used once. This is because the type system is not affine (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substructural_type_system).

Answer (score 0):

> Is using `dropWhile` like this bad style?

yes :-)

Comment: Using `dropWhile` isn't bad style at all.
It is using the original iterator after that, that's the problem.

Comment: You're right, it's not the `dropWhile` that's the issue.